# ng-repeat in AngularJS, Mongoose, Express

Tags: angularjs, express, mongoose

I'm learning MEAN stack.
Making simpe web app and i've faced one problem.

here is my angular code

```
<div>

<form class="somelecture" method="post" ng-submit="lecture()" name="lectureForm">

    <input ng-model="lecturetext" type="text" placeholder="text">

    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="lectureForm.$invalid">
        Send
    </button>
</form>

</div>

<div>
    <ul ng-repeat="lecture in lectures">
        <li>{{lecture.lecturetext}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is controller

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('AddCtrl', ['$scope', 'Addlecture', function($scope, Addlecture) {
        $scope.lecture = function() {
            Addlecture.lecture({
                lecturetext: $scope.lecturetext
            });
        };
    }]);
```

and that's factory for it

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('Addlecture', ['$http', '$location', '$rootScope', '$cookieStore', '$alert',
        function($http, $location, $rootScope, $cookieStore, $alert) {

            return {
                lecture: function(lecture) {
                    return $http.post('/api/lecture', lecture)
                        .success(function(data) {
                            $location.path('/add');

                            $alert({
                                title: '',
                                content: 'norm',
                                placement: 'bottom-left',
                                type: 'success',
                                duration: 3
                            });
                        })
                        .error(function() {
                            $alert({
                                title: '',
                                content: 'some wrong',
                                placement: 'bottom-left',
                                type: 'danger',
                                duration: 3
                            });
                        });
                }
            };
```

here is what happens on the server express

```
app.post('/api/lecture', function(req, res, next) {
    var lecture = new Lecture({
        lecturetext: req.body.lecturetext
    });
    lecture.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(200);
    });
});
```

I can see in my database that post text adding correctly, but ng-repeat doesnt show all the ((lecturetext)) of them. 
I know that something wrong with my server code - but what exactly.
I've also deleted app.get code - cause it's incorrect. What should my app.get code look like on the server, to show all "lecture in lectures" in ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I see you are only sending a response with no data from the server to the client, how are you going to pass the lecturetest list to the client?

my suggestion is to send a json response and read it in your $resource object tipically the flow is the following: (let's assume that you are using moongose)

```
app.post('/api/lecture', function(req, res, next) {
    var lecture = new Lecture({
        lecturetext: req.body.lecturetext
    });
    lecture.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        //nested operation, save and get list of lectures
        lecture.find({param: anyParam }, function(err, doc){
            if(err){
                return next(err); 
            }else{
                //send information as json
                res.send(200, {data: doc});
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In the client side could be something like:

```
var LectureEndPoint = $resource('/api/lecture');
var lecture = new LectureEndPoint();
lecture.$save(function(res){
 //return the value or do whatever you need to do to pass this information to your controller

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing the mark at your markup, try this and let me know:

```
<div>
    <ul ng-repeat="lecture in lectures">
        <li>{{lecture.lecturetext}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, i made mistake in the post - it's {{lecture.lecturetext}} in my code. SO it didn't help.

Comment: no problem! The next step is checking if your request is being processed by your server and if it is returning the expected response. To make it easy, put a `console.log(data)` at the top of your success function and paste it here.

Comment: server responds correctly -
POST /api/lecture 200 12ms - 2b

Comment: Well, now I see you are posting the lecture, but you are never asking for a list of lectures back... you should get them and assign them to the `$scope.lectures` if you need help with that just let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So i have to write some app.get function on my server to get all lectures back? Help me with that - If it wouldn't be so hard for you)

Comment: I´m afraid I can only help you with the angular side... :(

Comment: All I know is that you must set up an endpoint that loads and returns all your Lectures, having done that you can call it from angular

Comment: Do you think something wrong with my success function? 
as far as i understand (i'm very new to this) - i can't get all the list of lectures from database with only angular - or can i?